# R SQL: Is the Default Option Sampling WITH Replacement?

Tags: sql, r, random, dbi

I want to sample a file WITH REPLACEMENT on a server using SQL with R:

Pretend that this file in the file I am trying to sample:

```
library(dplyr)
library(DBI)

con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")
dbWriteTable(con, "iris", iris)
```

I want to sample with replacement 30 rows where species = setosa and 30 rows where species = virginica. I used the following code to do this:

```
rbind(DBI::dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM iris WHERE (`Species` = 'setosa') ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 30;"), DBI::dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM iris WHERE (`Species` = 'virginica') ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 30;"))
```

However at this point, I am not sure if the random sampling being performed is WITH REPLACEMENT or WITHOUT REPLACEMENT.

- Can someone please help me determine if the random sampling being performed is WITH REPLACEMENT or WITHOUT REPLACEMENT - and if it is being done WITHOUT REPLACEMENT, how can I change this so that its done WITH REPLACEMENT?

Thank you!

Comment: SQL uses set based arithmetic.  Once a record has been returned from the table, that record is considered as consumed and won't be returned a second time.

Comment: @ Tim: Thank you for this piece of information! I wonder if there is a way to change this by modifying the query... I will start looking into this!

Comment: any more information on the actual data you're working with?  i.e. why not just grab everything (iris is only 150 rows) and use `sample` in R

Comment: also, if that sampling without replacement has acceptable performance, then I'd just use that and resample appropriately in R so that you end up with the same distribution as if you'd just sampled with replacement directly

Comment: @ Sam Mason : Thank you for leaving a comment! I am interested in learning if random sampling with replacement can be done in R!